# Doubly linked node constructor in c++

Tags: c++, constructor, doubly-linked-list

I am trying to make a node for a doubly linked list in c++, but experiencing some problems with the constructor. I have the following simplyfied header file:

```
class Node{
public:
    Node();
private:
    int data;
    Node* next;
    Node* previous;
};
```

My .cpp file looks as the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int data;
Node* next;
Node* previous;

Node::Node(){
    data = 0;
    next = NULL;
    previous = NULL;
}
```

I get the following error when compiling this: "Node does not name a type."

I have also tried to use 'struct' to create the Node:

```
struct Node{
     int data;
     Node* next;
     Node* previous;
}
```

But this however gives me another error on the constructor in the cpp file:
"definition of implicitly-declared ...."

How can I make this program compile without error messages by using a constructor and  variables, and what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't included the header that defines `Node`.

Comment: I feel extremly embarrassed for forgetting this. Thank you very much, this solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have to include the header with Node definition in your cpp module. Also I think these statements in the cpp module

```
int data;
Node* next;
Node* previous;
```

must be deleted.

You could define the constructor inside the class definition. I would define it as

```
class Node{
public:
    Node( int data, Node *next = 0, Node *previous = 0 ) 
        : data( data ), next( next ), previous( previous )
    {
    }
private:
    int data;
    Node* next;
    Node* previous;
};
```